# JSP Expression language syntax

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page which is already developed.  Below I am mentioning the line which I did not understand in that JSP page

```
<c:forEach items='${info.orders}' var='order' varStatus='status'>
```

In above line I did not understand  from where info. comes and I checked in built in objects of expression language but this info object is not present

Comment: There should be reference of info defined in jsp scriplet. e.g. <%Info info =...%> or in the jsp that might be included in it using @include.

Comment: `info` can come from many places, depending on the technology you're using. JSP only, Servlet, Spring, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`info` should be an attribute being set in back end Java code ( `Servlet` etc ). Check your back end Java code to figure out ( if its not being set in `JSP` with `<c:set var=` ).

Whatever Java class this attribute `info` represents must have a method, `getOrders` which might be returning a `List` i.e. `info` class must have a field `orders`.

Without access to your code base, its very hard to answer precisely esp. not knowing if there are any frameworks being used.

You should do an exact word search for `info` in your code base as this doesn't look like a **built in** object.

Answer (score 0):

long time ago i did JSP, but I believe you can set variables in JSP (besides the built-in like session, request).

Like

```
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:out value="${salary}"/>
```

Comment: That would assign a simple *value*, not an object with `orders` field.